# Spring boot data not uploaded

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I build spring boot application, but the problem is I want to upload images on the web browser but it does not work, I run the app on IntelliJ IDEA, here is the code: *https://github.com/rmalav15/siamese-tf-java*
please help, here is the code that backs the error (Unable to Enroll Due to some error)

```
package com.tensorflow.siamese.controllers;

import com.tensorflow.siamese.models.User;
import com.tensorflow.siamese.services.EnrollmentService;
import com.tensorflow.siamese.services.ImageProcessingService;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/enroll")
@Slf4j
public class EnrollmentController {

@Value("${images.save.path:src/main/resources/Images}")
private String path;

@Autowired
private EnrollmentService enrollmentService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/new", method = RequestMethod.POST)
ResponseEntity enrollNew(@RequestParam("name") String name,
                         @RequestParam("files") List<MultipartFile> images) {

    try {
        List<Path> imagePaths = new ArrayList<>();
        for (MultipartFile file : images) {
            imagePaths.add(ImageProcessingService.write(file, path));
        }
        User user = enrollmentService.enrollNew(imagePaths, name);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(user);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.debug("Exception in enrollNew Apia", e);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body("Unable to Enroll Due to some error.");
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace of the exception ?

Comment: can we talk on hangout? or any other platforms, this is my account: shalaw.00115594@gmail.com.

Comment: It would be helpful to everyone who is trying to answer this question if you add the stacktrace here only

Comment: actually I don't know what is stacktrace? if you are interested to help me, please I will explain it in a short video. shalaw.00115594@gmail.com